# How to create white volumetric clouds in a dark scene?

Tags: volumetrics

I am trying to create a scene which has a black background and the only ways to create volumetric clouds that i've seen results in ones which look believeable in light scenes but in dark ones they completely disappear. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all clouds can't be seen in total black night. We can see them only when moon shine a bit. So it's pretty accurate result.

But if you need you could just mix your material with emission shader.

Comment: I have no clue why I didnt just do that in the first place, I was plugging things like that into the surface instead and never even thought to just mix it with my material, the effects of working at 3 am lol.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe work with layers. The scene with the clouds on one transparent layer and a second layer with the dark background. And merge these layers in the compositor.